# MySQL name and surname in 2 columns vs name in 1 column

Tags: php, mysql, performance

One simple question and I couldn't find any answers to id :

Should name be in 2 different DB columns ( name / surname ) or in 1 column ( name + surname ) ?

In all the projects I had they were in 2 different columns, but now I have to start a new project and I was wantering how it better to store it. I mean, the 2 different columns gave me a bit of trouble and sometimes slowed performance down. Please note this very important thing :

- A very important part of the public part of the site will be an advanced search and it WILL search for the full name in about 200k records.

So, what do you suggest ? 2 columns or 1 ? I am inclined twords the 1 column solution because I cannot find any advantages in using 2, but maybe I am wrong ?

**EDIT**

Thank you for the answers. The only reason for this question was for the performance issue, I need all the extra boost I can get.

Comment: I would pick 2, as you can easily sort by surname or first name, or select accordingly

Comment: Again a programmer that doesn't notice the middlename. So split up to 3: `firstname`, `middlename`, `surname`

Comment: storing data inside a database system means also having structured data. therefor I split all mixed contents into smallest peaces - fields.

Comment: @Bondye : You presume that all countries have the concept of the middle name and that is false.

Comment: @Bondye Do you know what "concept" means ? If not, find out instead of replying with no meaning.

Comment: @Cosmin LOL, if you are a programmer of concepts I wish you all the luck in the future. Middlenames are not depending on a country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of a relational database is to relate data. If you store a full name (e.g. John Smith) in a single field, you lose the ability to easily separate out the first and last names.

If you store them in separate fields, you can VERY easily rejoin them into a single full name, but it's quite difficult to reliably pull a name apart into separate first + last name components.

Answer (score 3):

Two columns is much more flexible. Eg.

- Do you ever want to sort by surname?
- Do you ever want to address the person formally (eg: Dear Mr Cosmin)?
- Will you ever want to search by surname and not forename, or vice versa?

200K records is a trivial amount in any properly designed database.

You may find this an interesting read on the subject of [names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

With two columns, you can sort by surname without having to do expensive substring operations in your select statement.  It is easy to do a CONCAT to get the full name in situations that call for it, but harder to parse the last name out of names such as "John Doe-Smith" or "John Doe III".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I'd rather designed it as **two different colmns** because you can have various ways to handle the record. About performance issue, add an index on two columns to make faster searching.

There are times when you want to search for `John Doe` and wanting that even it is reverse `Doe John` but still matches to `John Doe`. That's one advantage of having separate fields on the name.

Sample design of schema,

```
CREATE TABLE PersonList
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(25),
    LastName VARCHAR(25),
    -- other fields here,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (FirstName, LastName)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 columns helps you in:

- easy sorting data by surname
- communication with user by name (eg. "Hello Michael" used on many websites etc.)
- displaying a lot of data in multiple columns (you can display only surname when you have no space on screen)

Names stored in format "Surname Name" is still easy to sort, but may be seen as inelegant in some countries.